# How to add bass to a female vocal track in Nuendo 4?

Tags: audio-recording, nuendo4

While I am recording a female vocal,the treble,as I see,gets really high,which I am finding difficult to control.I want to add more bass to the track in order to resolve the issue.Will adjusting the low-mid frequencies help in any way?Any suggestion regarding this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does the voice sound unpleasant? Generally you want to reproduce voices faithfully, not change them drastically.

Comment: Yes,it lacks bass and sounds pretty unpleasant.

Comment: "Lacks bass" in what way? A soprano vocal will never contain anything vaguely in the bass frequencies. If the singer is shrill or what I'd call "a bit 2k" then pull those frequencies, don't try to push ones that aren't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an equalizer you can only work with content that's already present in the recording. If you boost 80 Hz but there's no content at that frequency, you've achieved nothing.

I'd do this in two steps:

1. get rid of the peak at high frequencies.
2. Boost the low frequencies a bit: apply a broad filter to catch e.g. the entire lower octave. Don't overdo this, because voices quickly start to sound unnatural when you apply too much EQ.

A spectrogram will help here.